# Dota 2 Plugin (Values end up being assigned to all units)

Tags: javascript, game-engine

Here is my Code
http://pastebin.com/RXUNxcct
What i would like to know is, how i can use my list to only affect the listed units?

Comment: Can you explain a little better what you want? If you're trying to only affect a certain list of Heroes/units, I would put them all into a list and then use that list as what you check to see if a unit is "listed" with a foreach (not sure if JS has them?) or for loop.

Comment: I like to check the complete list of Units to be affected with the Complete List of Units Available. (so that only the units i want are buffed). The Problem seems to be that even when i get some code to work it affect the keyvalues for all units rather then only the specified ones. I will upload a shortet pastebin so anyone can take a look at the specified part.

Comment: Sadly i cant edit the previous post so here is the [link](http://pastebin.com/qxtMdUzp)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, here is some pseudocode:

I would first put both sets into two lists or arrays. One array/list for the total heroes, and one for the "to be buffed" heroes. I would then check each element of the total heroes list, and see if the current hero that you are working with (through a for-loop, perhaps?) is in the "to be buffed" list. If so, buff it.

Let me know if this helps you.